# Difference between passing “pointer to pointer” and “address of pointer” to a function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strtok, addressof

I have a function that takes a `char **`; it uses it internally for maintaining context between successive calls.

What is the difference between defining `char **x` and passing `x` to it, and defining `char *x` and passing `&x`?

---

**For context:** I tried to implement the example at [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) man page on my own before reading the source code. And I got segfaults. Then after attempts I looked at the source.

The problem was that I defined `char **x` and passed `x` as the `**saveptr` argument, but changing the definition to `char *x` and the passing to `&x` solved the problem.

What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version, with `char **x;` and passing `x`, creates and uses an uninitialised pointer to pointer to char.
The second version, with `char * x;` and passing `&x`, creates an uninitialised pointer to char, but passes a value which is a valid address of a pointer to char, and is a defined value (i.e. like an initialised pointer to uninitialised pointer to char).

Basically with first version you ask to write at a "random" place in memory (almost sure way to get a segfault); with second, you ask to write into an existing pointer variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you define e.g.

```
char **x;
```

Then you simply define a pointer. It doesn't matter that it's a pointer to another pointer, the important part is that it's just a pointer. And as such, with the definition shown above, it's not initialized. It doesn't point anywhere special. Dereferencing it, like you most likely do in the function, leads to *undefined behavior*.

On the other hand, with a definition like

```
char *x;
```

and using `&x` to get a pointer to it, the pointer returned by `&x` points somewhere valid, to the variable `x`. Dereferencing `&x` will allow the function to access and modify `x` itself.

Using the address-of operator in this way is a way to emulate *pass by reference*, which C doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I never noticed that dereferencing an uninitialized pointer leads to undefined behavior (I thought it only causes segfault), and that passing by reference is simulated in C.

Answer (score 0):

Because all function arguments are **passed by value** in C, if you define `char **x` and pass `x`, it won't be modified by the function. If you define `char *x` and pass `&x`, it can be modified (change its pointing address).

Comment: That's depend on where `x` is pointing to. If you write `char** x = &ptr_char`, and then pass that `x` to the function, you can change were `ptr_char` points to by `*x = new_address`.